# Convert PHP hash_hmac(sha512) to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, hmac

I am porting a php script to node, and I don't know much about encryption.

The php script uses this function:

```
hash_hmac('sha512', text, key);
```

So, I need to implement a function in Node js for returning a keyed hash using the hmac method (SHA512).

From what I can see, node has this functionality built in via the crypto module (http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) -- But I unclear how to reproduce this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, use the crypto library.

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key);
hash.update(text);
var hashed_data = hash.digest();
```

More details (e.g. arguments to digest to control the output encoding from `hash.digest`) are at [the link](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html) you provided.

As Nick points out, you will need to do this entire process each time you want to encrypt a new string (i.e. create a new `hash` object via `crypto.createHmac`.)

Comment: Tip when using this, I think you can only call the digest() method on a hash once. This means that you cannot use update(), followed by digest() to form another hash. If you need to form multiple hashes, you will have to use crypto.createHmac() multiple times.

Comment: Yes, this is correct as far as I know. Thanks, I'll update my answer.